I get stressed in cases that I fail to extract a specific task(s) of deliverables when I am asked to do something
In my recent work, I was asked to research something, but I failed to understand the deliverable and the purpoce. Upon discussion, I was getting same response despite my ability to structure the requested stuff as a task and trying to ask clarification question, so I can formulate a task.
My position is as a software engineer into a small team. My boss made the company since grad and is ~5yr younger than me. In my case I have a 5yr experience as coding.
I have trouble on face-to-face verbal communication, but I can code and make tutorials whilst I managed to make presentation in various conferences. Usually if I do not understand what to deliver and in what form (code or test) I feel stressed.
Due to my stress and anxiety, I yelled at my boss (I know it was wrong, but I was about to blow and I don't know how to manage it or in what professional could help me to manage it). Also, I get stressed when I feel for tasks that are out of my waters and I do not know how to manage it, same applies if I find no reason on what I am doing.
I feel like I want something familiar in order to deliver and be performant. Especially when I feel like the steps takes makes no sense. Also, I feel like I may not get a satisfactory result.
Usually upon my usual task I rely upon personal work I did in my free time or prior knowledge base. Doing something new and fail to understand the format of the deliverable (is it code is it a text is it a list) upon chaos I fail to be productive.
I tried to think about it and I realised that:

Working as a software developer may not match my personality. I feel comfortable doing same thing again and again. As a software engineer I have to also undestand not techincal stuff
I may have a strong ego and I have no idea how to humble myself. What to do, how do I start. (Yelling and getting stressed may be an indication of strong ego.)

Tried to discuss it with my former colleagues, as a means of counselling, and self-improvement, but still I fail to keep a permanent contact.
Do you knwo how I can manage it.

I don't mean this in a judgemental way at all, but have you ever been diagnosed with any part of the autism spectrum?  Many of the challenges you outlined are extremely common with that.  People can be high functioning and successful, but thru no fault of their own, struggle socially like this.  I suggest reaching out to a doctor or licensed therapist, who can help guide you with strategies to make life a little easier. Good luck my friend.

This is more a personal development and stress management question then a workspace question, as we have been defining it here. The same reactions could occur on a non-work project, or one that is being conducted solo rather than as part of a team. There have been many books written on time management and stress Management, and there are people with expertise in helping you develop those skills.

Normal stress management may not be sufficient in your case. This situation would do better with a professional who can go over things in more detail and offer more specific advice. Then, there are the many different facets of software engineering and working in a different environment might fit your personality better. A mentor might help you there.

@RC_23 No I have not I have not searched it through but I note it down and I am seeking a specialist.

The comments from RC_23 and keshlam really go hand-in-hand. I have two adult childern and an employee on the spectrum. Your post could be describing various interactions with each of them.
Keep in mind that your employer wants you to succeed. You will need help from time to time when you need clarification. What is in your head is very focused. What your boss is thinking of is likely something else. As you pointed out, it is this communication that is causing you the stress.
The disconnect is because you and your boss have a different focus and aren't/can't put the same effort into your questions. You both will need to meet in the middle. You by taking the time to remember that they are NOT thinking about the DETAILS what you are focused on. That means you'll need to bring them up to speed on the issues. They will need to give you the time to do this correctly.
Consider asking to speak to you boss about coming up with a plan for when you need clarification and how to escalate when you feel nervious. The last part is important because there will be times that you may want an answer, but your boss can't give you their full attention. In those cases having a backup plan for what you should work on or study might be helpful in holding down the stress.

One way to reassure yourself might be to tell your employer how you are planning on approaching the task, and ask them if they think that will work and will cover everything.

In my case I tried to create a focused deliverable when I was asked upon something like deliver X-Y thing that is tangible whereas the task is a generic search. Upon generic search WHAT I need to do and how can be tackled. I feel like I am jumped around and like a ship floating in the ocean. When I was asked about clarification I felt that I still was stormed with same thing that I could not understand. Also, usually when I explain stuff I can do it written and with visualy and not just verbally, verbally I fail to explain stuff good enough.
